# PHP checkbox echo errors syntax error

Tags: javascript, php

I get a Parse error: syntax error when I echo 2 checkbox rows. I think there is something with the 2nd  tag because the first checkbox: FILM DRAAI DAGEN. echo's right.

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo 'Film draai dagen: ';?>
    </td>
    <td>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['draaidag']))
{
    foreach($_POST['draaidag']as$check)
    {
        echo " ".$check;
        $draaidag = " ".$check;
    }
?>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo 'Film tijd dagen: ';?>
    </td>
    <td>
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['tijddag']))
{
    foreach($_POST['tijddag']as$check)
    {
        echo " ".$check;
        $tijddag = " ".$check;
    }
?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You didn't close your second if statement

Comment: @BrianPatterson I closed it right or am I blind? xd

Comment: Blind ... You closed the foreach but not the IF

Comment: See my answer.   Its missing on both loops.

Comment: Please accept if it works :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @BrianPatterson and riggs thx for the help I accepted the question

Comment: Glad to help.  Gl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Syntax error means your code has errors.   In this case you did not close the if statement.   Simply add a curly brace at the end before your closing tag.

```
<td>
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['draaidag']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['draaidag']as$check)
        {
            echo " ".$check;
            $draaidag = " ".$check;
        }
    } //<--- this guy
?>
</td>
```